# Meaning of reference radius in multipole expansion

Tags: electrostatics, potential, terminology, multipole-expansion

I have a given electrostatic potential $\Phi(x,y)$ in 2D and want to see how different it is from a some multipole potential (eg. quadropole).

The expansion in the multipole terms is

$\Phi(x,y)= \Phi_0 + P_{1,1} x/R_{ref} - P_{1,2} y/R_{ref}+P_{2,1} (x^2-y^2)/R^2_{ref} - P_{2,2} 2xy/R^2_{ref} + ...$

However, nowhere I have found an explanation what is the interpretation of the coefficients $P_{i,j}$ for a given reference radius $R_{ref}$ (eg. [here](https://cas.web.cern.ch/sites/default/files/lectures/bruges-2009/wolski-1.pdf) they only mention it can be chosen arbitrarily). Does the reference radius gives the radius of a sphere, on which surface I compare the potentials? And depending on the radius of the sphere the potential can be more or less like quadropole or other moments?
I.e. exemplary for a small reference radius the field seems to be very like quadropole (so by ploting the potential on a sphere of this radius it would with high accuracy be identical to a quadropole potential, but to which value of $P_{2,j}$ this would correspond? - around 1?) but from the far away more like dipole? As the origin of the sphere, I would then choose where my potential is zero.

I would be also grateful for some relevant references.

Comment: Could you clarify where the term "reference radius" comes from? I am familiar with multipole expansion as described in Griffiths's text, but unfortunately am not familiar with this term.

Comment: I have added a reference and written the expansion explicitly, I hope it will help.